# Python reportlab, cannot add a table inside a frame

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying add a few lines of text and a table inside a frame. Adding paragraph works fine but when I add the table I get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Annual_qc/Report Generation/draft.py", line 175, in <module>
    frame.addFromList(Story,  c)
  File "G:\ReportLab_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\frames.py", line 299, in addFromList
    if self.add(head,canv,trySplit=0):
  File "G:\ReportLab_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\frames.py", line 167, in _add
    s =flowable.getSpaceBefore()
TypeError: getSpaceBefore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

See the MRE below.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Spacer, Frame, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib import colors

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles["Normal"]

c = Canvas('test.pdf')
frame = Frame(2*cm, 2*cm, 17*cm, 26*cm, showBoundary=1)
Story = []

pText1 = "<font size='12'>{}</font>".format("Title")
Story.append(Paragraph(pText1, styleN))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
pText2 = "<font size='12'>{}</font>".format("Some text")
Story.append(Paragraph(pText2, styleN))

data = [["c11", "c12", "c13", "c14"],
        ["c21", "c22", "c23", "c24"]]

table = Table(data)
table.colWidths = [5, 3, 3, 3]
table.hAlign = 'CENTER'
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.red),
    ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black)
]))

Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
Story.append(Table)

frame.addFromList(Story,  c)
c.save()
```

Comment: What is `Table`? If it is class then you should use `()` to create instance `Story.append( Table() )` OR maybe you need existing instance `table` instead of class `Table` - `Story.append(table)`

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` only for classes - like `Frame`, `Canvas`, - but `lower_case_names` for variables - ie. `store` instead of `Store`

Comment: I actually used lower case (table) above but my mistake is where I appended the Table instead of table. Thanks for pointing it out!